# How to get php class functions' comments?

Tags: php, reflection, comments, eaccelerator

I need to get a comment of the particular function in php class, for example:

```
/* Some commets for a class */
class Foo extends Bar {
    function __construct() {}

    // a single line comment to the function foo()
    function foo() {}

    /* a multi-line comment
    to the function bar() */
    public static function bar() {}

}
```

Yes i know, that could be easily done with ReflectionMethod->getDocComment(), but it does not work for me because i use eAccelerator and it cuts all comments from the code, so that getDocComment always returns FALSE.

I don't want to recompile eAccelerator too :)

I need a function like this:

```
function get_function_comment($class_contents, $function_name) {}
```

so that i will return a function's comment, $class_contents is a variable wich stores the class content as in the example above.

I tried to do it myself but i can't create a proper regexp..

Please help me :)

Comment: I don't think a single regular expression is going to cut it.

Comment: You're not going to be able to write a regex that implements the entirety of PHP's syntax parser...

Comment: If this is possible at all without a *lot* of messing around, [Tokenizer](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) will be the way to do it.

Comment: `getDocComment` only returns specifically formatted comments that the parser deems as `T_DOC_COMMENT`'s. It doesn't return other comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using proper phpDoc comments:

```
/**
 * Something explaining this
 *
 * @return string
 */
function foo(){  }
```

Comment: It does not matter what comments to use. eAccelerator will cut it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, I almost feel dirty for writing this regex, but this might do the trick (haven't tested it, so don't take my word).

```
preg_match('#(//.*$|/\*.*\*/)\s*$[\s\w]*function\s+$function_name\b#Usmi', $class_contents, $result);
```

In theory, it works like:

- Find either:

  - // and everything till the end of that line OR
  - /*, then everything until an */
- Then eat all the whitespace till the end of line
- Take any amount of whitespace or word characters on the next line until you hit "function", some whitespace, then the whole function name you want.

In practice: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Comment: Actually this does not work when class has comments too. Like this:


`    /** CMS users management */`
`    class Adminusers extends Module {`

`    }`

So it returns the text from the beginning of class contents to required function name. But i need just function's comment :)